# State not updating on action when receiving promise from axios request

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios

I'm new to React and am working on a project where I would like to update my redux state whenever a new object is added successfully. I have my API setup and can make the requests successfully via postman but whenever running on the client it seems like the promise is not being returned in time from the axios request or the data is not available. I am puzzled. I would appreciate any help, go easy on me I am new lol.

I have stepped through the debugger and all data that I need is being returned through response.data but whenever I assign it to the state to be updated it is not updating. If I move the return outside of the .then then I can return the object but it does not contain the response... which is important.

```
/* This is my reducer that is calling axios request from a JSService. Axios 
request is working and returning appropriate res.data. The newObject 
attribute is not being applied to state when mapping state to props. */


// Not working
case
ADD_OBJECT: 
  objectService.saveObject(action.payload.object)
    .then((res) => {
      return {
        ...state,
        newObject: res.data,
      }
    }.catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    }

return { ...state };


// Action
export const addObject = object => ({
  type: ADD_OBJECT,
  payload: { object },
});

// Axios Request
export const addObject = object => axios.post('/api/ObjectData/add', object);

// Component
class AddNew extends Component {
 state = { title: '', roleId: '' };
 onSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   const newEntry = this.state;
   const { setObject, history } = this.props;
   setObject(newEntry);
   history.push('/objects/nextPage');
 }

 onChange = (e) => {
   this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
 }

 render() {
   const { title, roleId } = this.state;
   return(
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
          <input type="text" className="form-control" name="title" onChange={this.onChange} value={title} />
        <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
      </form>
    </div>
   );
 }
}
function mapStateToProps({ data }){
  return { data };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return ({
    setObject: (object) => { dispatch(addObject(object)); },
  )};
}
```

Expected results would be that newObject would contain res.data in my reducer.

Comment: Please add the component where you're dispatching `addObject` from

Comment: Axios requests have to be made before going to the reducer. The reducer should be used in axios.then() callback of its promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Redux docs:

> The only way to change the state is to emit an action, an object
>   describing what happened. **Do not put API calls into reducers**. Reducers
>   are just pure functions that take the previous state and an action,
>   and return the next state. Remember to return new state objects,
>   instead of mutating the previous state.

Ref: https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions